# getting all dbpedia predicate list

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to get all dbpedia predicate (labels of property). Check this link

http://dbpedia.org/page/Akshay_Kumar

I wan to get,

```
dbpedia-owl:abstract
dbpedia-owl:birthDate
dcterms:subject
dc:description
rdfs:label
owl:sameAs
foaf:givenName
```

in short, all properties on left column. Not for this entity only but entire list.

Please see, only properties can be retrived using:

```
select distinct ?property where {
         ?instance a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> . 
         ?instance ?property ?obj . }
```

or

```
SELECT * { ?x a rdf:Property }
```

but I want with `prefix` like `dbpedia-owl`, `dc`, `foaf`, `rdfs` etc

Comment: What do you mean by " I want with prefix like dbpedia-owl, dc, foaf, rdfs etc"  Are you trying to restrict which properties you select?  Or you're trying to format them nicely?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I wan to format them properly, should look like `dbpedia-owl:birthDate
dcterms:subject
dc:description`

Comment: Does [SPARQL query to get all class label with namespace prefix defined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17939197/1281433) address the question?  It's asking about classes rather than properties, but the point is the same;  how to get `dbpedia-owl:foo` instead of `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/foo`.  Does it work for you, since you already know how to get the properties?

Comment: (At the risk of self promotion, I think you may find [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17949002/1281433) to that question a little bit cleaner than the accepted one.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I tried on dbpedia endpoint, it gives empty result

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried, since you didn't update the question with the new attempt.  Clearly, the answer on that question doesn't solve this exact problem;  you'd have to modify it accordingly.  This approach **does** work though;  see the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on a modification of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17949002/1281433) to [SPARQL query to get all class label with namespace prefix defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17939197/1281433).

```sql
select distinct ?prettyName ?property where {

  #-- get distinct properties that are used on Persons
  { select distinct ?property where {
      [ a dbpedia-owl:Person ; ?property [] ]
    } }

  #-- specify some URIs that are used as 
  #-- prefixes and the prefix name that 
  #-- gets used
  values (?prefixURI ?prefixName) {
    (dbpedia-owl: "dbpedia-owl")
    (dbpprop:     "dbpprop")
    (foaf:        "foaf")
    #-- ...more...
  }

  #-- only consider those properties that
  #-- begin with one of the prefixes
  filter strstarts(str(?property),str(?prefixURI))

  #-- generate the pretty name
  bind(concat(?prefixName,":",strafter(str(?property),str(?prefixURI))) as ?prettyName)
}
limit 1000
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3FprettyName%20%3Fproperty%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20get%20distinct%20properties%20that%20are%20used%20on%20Persons%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20select%20distinct%20%3Fproperty%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20[%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson%20%3B%20%3Fproperty%20[]%20]%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20specify%20some%20URIs%20that%20are%20used%20as%20%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20prefixes%20and%20the%20prefix%20name%20that%20%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20gets%20used%0D%0A%20%20values%20%28%3FprefixURI%20%3FprefixName%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28dbpedia-owl%3A%20%22dbpedia-owl%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28dbpprop%3A%20%20%20%20%20%22dbpprop%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28foaf%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22foaf%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20only%20consider%20those%20properties%20that%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20begin%20with%20one%20of%20the%20prefixes%0D%0A%20%20filter%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fproperty%29%2Cstr%28%3FprefixURI%29%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20generate%20the%20pretty%20name%0D%0A%20%20bind%28concat%28%3FprefixName%2C%22%3A%22%2Cstrafter%28str%28%3Fproperty%29%2Cstr%28%3FprefixURI%29%29%29%20as%20%3FprettyName%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%201000&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
prettyName                        property
-------------------------------------------------------
dbpprop:hasPhotoCollection        http://dbpedia.org/property/hasPhotoCollection
dbpprop:subWins                   http://dbpedia.org/property/subWins
foaf:homepage                     http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/homepage
dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink  http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink
...
```