# Get all (Dutch) properties from DBPedia including prefixes

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I have to create a Q&A system with which I can answer questions using SPARQL and DBpedia. Currently I have to make many useless queries to DBpedia with non-existing properties. I have tried to obtain all properties and put it in a txt file, however I don't get the prefixes with it.

My SPARQL query is as follows:

```
select distinct str(COALESCE(?property2, ?property)) as ?property where
{
?instance a <%s> . 
?instance ?property ?obj .
OPTIONAL{?property rdfs:label ?property2}
}
```

where `s` is a link to a label obtained from DBpedia as well (I do this using Python) like the following:

```
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Amphibian"
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AmusementParkAttraction"
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AnatomicalStructure"
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Animal"
```

The output I get from the query (in CSV) is:

```
"prijzengeld loopbaan ($)" "Verluste" "casualties" "pertes"
"verliezen" "Kategorie" "categorie"
```

I would like to have the prefixes included, so for example:

- `prop-nl:`
- `dbpedia-owl:`
- etc.

Especially the `prop-nl` is important since I have to use the Dutch property names.

Comment: ?property (in the query) is the URI;  that's what you actually want, isn't it?  The human readable prefixes, like "prop-nl", "dbpedia-owl", etc., are just abbreviations for some text.  And DBpedia actually changes some of their predefined ones, so `dbpedia-owl:foo` used to work on the public endpoint, but now it doesn't;  you'd have to use `dbo:foo`.  But `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/foo>` would always work.

Comment: But if that's what you want to do, you might find an answer in [SPARQL query to get all class label with namespace prefix defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939197/sparql-query-to-get-all-class-label-with-namespace-prefix-defined/17949002)

Comment: Thanks! So instead of just asking the names of the properties (like prop-nl:jaar) I could do <http://nl.dbpedia.org/property/jaar>? So I guess therefore I wouldn't need the prefix? I think I'll just do that then instead of shortening the URI's by hand using the link you gave. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**?property** (in the **where** part of the query) is the URI;  that's what you actually want, isn't it?  The human readable prefixes, like "prop-nl", "dbpedia-owl", etc., are just abbreviations for some text.  And DBpedia actually changes some of their predefined ones, so `dbpedia-owl:foo` used to work on the public endpoint, but now it doesn't;  you'd have to use `dbo:foo`.  But `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/foo>` would always work.

But if that's what you want to do, you might find an answer in [SPARQL query to get all class label with namespace prefix defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939197/sparql-query-to-get-all-class-label-with-namespace-prefix-defined/17949002)